# Create a multiline description of a formpage?

Tags: cloud-deploy, formpage

I am currently making a formpage with a very long description. And I'd like to structure the description. However I can't put in line breakes like \n.
It worked fine on the formpage but when cloud-deployed it removes all newlines.

A example would be the following:

```
   CloudDeploy@
     FormPage["x" -> Number, 
      AppearanceRules -> <|"Description" -> "Line1\nLine2"|>]
```

This doesn't work while

```
    FormPage["x" -> Number, 
              AppearanceRules -> <|"Description" -> "Line1\nLine2"|>]
```

Does work.

Comment: Please provide a sample for readers to consider.

Comment: Maybe because you used a forward slash and not a backward slash "/n" =!= "\n"

Comment: It is because `\n` is ignored by the browser unless `pre` tag is used. Try with `Colunm` or  `"Line1<br>Line2"`